# BCP detects CRLF as data and not as Row ending

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I am using bcp to export and import data, for example:

```
bcp "exec db.dbo.procedure" queryout "C:\Users\I\Desktop\ps.dat" -c -r "*" -t; -S -U -P

bcp db.dbo.table in C:\Users\I\Desktop\ps.dat -e "C:\Users\I\Desktop\ps_error.dat" -c -r "*" -t; -m1000000 -S -U -P
```

If I execute these statements without `-r`, `bcp` uses the default `CRLF` as end of row. Later, the import fails with right data truncation.

After so many attempts I have seen that `CRLF` is detected as two bytes of data, and it does not fit the table format. When I use the above statements it works perfectly.

Why is this happening? Is this a bcp bug, or is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MS that is the expected behaviour:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility

this article explains all the parameters and for this case these are the ones we are interested in:

-c

Performs the operation using a character data type. This option does not prompt for each field; it uses char as the storage type, without prefixes and with \t (tab character) as the field separator and \r\n (newline character) as the row terminator. -c is not compatible with -w.

-r

row_term
Specifies the row terminator. The default is \n (newline character). Use this parameter to override the default row terminator. For more information, see Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server).

So it seems that by removing -r which sets the row terminator to \n (LF) , -c is taking over and setting the row terminator to \r\n (CRLF)

Comment: Yes, reading this it is clear that it is expected, but I do not understand why it does not detect that CRLF is row terminator, and avoid that as data...

Comment: I think that by removing the r on the import it assumes the default row terminator \n (LF) and the \r (CR) as data